# Are plain text user passwords supposed to be visible on CTRL + ALT + F1?

Tags: 18.04, login, password, security

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with encrypted home folders.

Are plain text user passwords supposed to be visible on CTRL + ALT + F1?

There are a few users on my workstation.  I've noticed while switching users that I can see my password for a split second after my GUI user session logs out and before the login GUI (GDM?) appears.  Watching for it, I can now see the other users' passwords as well.

Do I have something configured incorrectly?

I've searched for similar reports, but haven't found any.  I probably just haven't figured out the correct search terms.  I would appreciate pointers to already answered versions of my question.

Comment: "I've searched for similar reports, but haven't found any." Well... I clearly remember a topic about this though ;-) How about https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1803993  and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/issues/408

Comment: also take special attention to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/issues/408#note_301017

Comment: @Rinzwind  Consider writing an answer maybe?